# Javascript / React window.onerror fired twice

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to globally catch errors in my React application.

But every time the error is caught/forwarded twice to my registered function.

Example code:

```
window.onerror = (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) => {
console.log(msg)
  alert(msg)
}

class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)


  }

  render() {

    return (
      <button onClick={(e)=>{
        console.log("clicked")
        null.bla
      }}>
        Create an error

      </button>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

Here is a JS-fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dmxur0rc/4/

The console only shows one 'clicked' log, so it's not the button that fires twice, but the error event.

Answer (score 8):

I found a basic solution to this that should work in all scenarios.

It turns out that the object is identical in all calls, you could set up something to match them exactly, or you could just attach a custom attribute to the error object...

Admittedly this may only work with window.addEventListener('error', function...), as you are given the genuine error object as an argument, as opposed to window.onerror = function... which gets the data parts, such as message & lineNumber as opposed to the real error.

This is basically how I'm using it:

```js
window.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
  if (event.error.hasBeenCaught !== undefined){
    return false
  }
  event.error.hasBeenCaught = true
  // ... your useful code here
})
```

If this is called with the same error twice it will exit before getting to your useful code, only executing the useful code once per error.

Answer (score 7):

It is [known react error](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11499), related with implementation of error boundaries.

Comment: Interesting—never ran across this before.

Answer (score 5):

You need to return `true` from your error handler otherwise the default error handler will fire:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

> When the function returns true, this prevents the firing of the default event handler.

Also note that other error handlers may be in place via `addEventHandler`.

Comment: I updated the JS Fiddle to return true in the listener, but it still produces two alerts.

Comment: @fancy Did you try it outside of JSFiddle (you may have to generate a real error)?

Comment: Yes, I have this in my real project and then recreated in JSFiddle.
Do you have an idea how I can investigate / narrow it down?

Comment: @fancy I don't. I did note if I didn't alert, or logged just the error, it was no longer printing it twice/maybe start the. Also check a different browser, I used only Chrome.

Comment: Doesn't work for me also, but a solution from @Cameron Brown works in my case.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in other answers, the problem is in React in DEV mode. In this mode it [re-throws all exceptions](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10474) to "improve debugging experience".

#### I see 4 different error scenarios

1. Normal JS errors (for example, from an event handler, like in the question).

   These are sent to `window.onerror` **twice** by React's `invokeGuardedCallbackDev`.
2. JS errors that happen during `render`, and there is no React's [*error boundary*](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) in the components tree.

   The same as scenario 1.
3. JS errors that happen during `render`, and there is an *error boundary* somewhere in the components tree.

   These are sent to `window.onerror` **once** by `invokeGuardedCallbackDev`, but are also **caught** by the *error boundary's* `componentDidCatch`.
4. JS errors inside promises, that were not handled.

   These aren't sent to `window.onerror`, but rather to `window.onunhandledrejection`. And that happens only once, so no problem with this.

#### My workaround

```js
window.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
    const { error } = event;
    // Skip the first error, it is always irrelevant in the DEV mode.
    if (error.stack?.indexOf('invokeGuardedCallbackDev') >= 0 && !error.alreadySeen) {
        error.alreadySeen = true;
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
    // Normal error handling.
}, { capture: true });
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reference(s) for these 4 error scenarios?

Comment: I found these scenarios experimentally, there are no references.

Answer (score 1):

I use this error boundary to handle both React and global errors. Here is some advice from the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html):

- Error boundaries are React components that catch JavaScript errors anywhere in their child component tree, log those errors, and display a fallback UI instead of the component tree that crashed.
- A class component becomes an error boundary if it defines either (or
  both) of the lifecycle methods static getDerivedStateFromError() or
  componentDidCatch().
- Only use error boundaries for recovering from unexpected exceptions;
  don’t try to use them for control flow.
- Note that error boundaries only catch errors in the components below them in the tree; An error boundary can’t catch an error within itself.

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {

      state = {
        error: null,
      };
      lastError = null;

      // This lifecycle is invoked after an error has been thrown by a descendant component. It receives the error that was thrown as a parameter and should return a value to update state.
      static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
        // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
        return {
          error,
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        window.onerror = (msg, url, line, column, error) => {
          this.logError({
            error,
          });
        };
      }

      // getDerivedStateFromError() is called during the “render” phase, so side-effects are not permitted. For those use cases, use componentDidCatch() instead.

      // This lifecycle is invoked after an error has been thrown by a descendant component. It receives two parameters:

      // error - The error that was thrown.
      // info - An object with a componentStack key containing
      componentDidCatch(error, info) {
        // avoid calling log error twice
        if (this.lastError && this.lastError.message === this.state.error.message) {
          return true;
        }
        // Example "componentStack":
        //   in ComponentThatThrows (created by App)
        //   in ErrorBoundary (created by App)
        //   in div (created by App)
        //   in App
        // logComponentStackToMyService(info.componentStack);
        this.logError({
          error,
          info,
        });
      }

      async logError({
        error,
        info
      }) {
        this.lastError = error;

        try {
          await fetch('/error', {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(error),
          });
        } catch (e) {}
      }

      render() {
        if (this.state.error) {
          return  display error ;
        }

        return this.props.children;
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to store the last error's message in state and check when it happens for the second time.

```
export default MyComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {message: null};
  }

  componentDidMount(){
     const root = this;
     window.onerror = function(msg, url, line, column, error){
        if(root.state.message !== msg){
           root.setState({message: msg});

           // do rest of the logic
        }
     }
  }
}
```

> But anyways it is good idea to use [React Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html). And you can
>   implement this global javascript error handling inside the error
>   boundary component. Where you can both catch js errors (with
>   `window.onerror`) and React errors (with `componendDidCatch`).

Answer (score 0):

My workaround: Apply debouncing (in typescript):

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

let errorObserver: any;

window.onerror = (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) => {
  if (!errorObserver) {

    new Observable(observer => {
      errorObserver = observer
    }).pipe(debounceTime(300)) // wait 300ms after the last event before emitting last event
      .pipe(distinctUntilChanged()) // only emit if value is different from previous value
      .subscribe(handleOnError)
  }

  errorObserver.next(
    {
      msg,
      url,
      lineNo,
      columnNo,
      error
    }
  )

  return true
}

const handleOnError = (value: any) => {
  console.log('handleOnError', value)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

This looks like it's probably firing twice due to the nature of running it on JSFiddle. In a normal build process (with `webpack` and `babel`) code with a script error like that should fail to transpile.

Comment: It transpiles fine in my real project, I only reproduced it on JSFiddle